# Symmetric continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

Let (a_i)_{1<=i<=n} be a sequence of positive integers and c be a positive integer such that c divides a_1.
Suppose that we have this symmetric of continued fraction
[a_n, a_n-1,...,a_1]=c^{-1}[a_1, a_2, ...., a_n].
Can we assume that n is even and a_{n-k}=c^(-1)^{k+1}a_{k+1}, for 0<=k<=n-1?

Comment: I think that n is not even necessary

Comment: We should suppose that i>=2

Comment: n shoud be even for example

Comment: [a_3, a_2, a_1]=1/c[a_1,a_2, a_3]=[c^-1a_1, ca_2, c^-1a_3], so ca_2=a_2 impossible